# How to pdf print multiple cards with fixed size?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

How should I design a pdf in flutter that prints exactly sized i.e. on perforated paper.

My goal is a pdf with two columns and multiple rows. Inside the rows should be precisely positioned cards. The cards consist of images, QRCodes and tables generated from database data.

[image: Raw template reflecting the cutmarks of the printers paper]

Should I use a pw.Stack or the pw.GridView or a pw.Table?

Where does positioning work best?

Comment: Thanks for the advice with word merge. The thing is I need to print individual cards. And because I only have LibreOffice those templates do not show correctly there. I'll try again.